# Angular Universal with .Net6

Tags: .net, angular, .net-core, server-side-rendering

I use this repos https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/Ssr for create simple application .net angular and run it Server Side Rendring (universal). Its work for me as well. But when i publish this and run .exe file show me this error bellow.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware
> could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not
> found, and no other middleware handled the request.

Can anyone help whats my problem ?

Comment: Did you build the ClientApp so you have the ClienApp/dist/ in the same folder as the .exe ?

Comment: I did this, it didn't show the error anymore, but the problem was not solved. Can you tell me exactly what I should do? HenrikBøgelundLavstsen

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen

Comment: Can you update the questin if there is new errors ?